# How to compile and link for MIPS-I target?

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling

I'm using "toolchain-mipsel_3.3.6_BRCM24" and try compile and link for

1) ELF new 32-bit LSB executable, MIPS, MIPS-I version 1 (SYSV)

but instead of it I got this:

2) ELF new 32-bit LSB executable, MIPS, MIPS32 version 1 (SYSV)

however object files are compiled to this:

3) ELF new 32-bit LSB relocatable, MIPS, MIPS-I version 1 (SYSV)

I think that object files are compiled all right, but why it produces executables in format (2), not (1) ?

It looks like I need to pass some linker options, right ?

But if this is the case then I don't know which and how.
Please help. I didn't cross-compiled enything ever before.

btw. Output (1), (2) and (3) is generated by binwalk.

Comment: Does the executable work?

Comment: I did't try because I don't have an MIPS emulator installed and executables are for router's firmware. After that router's firmware extraction all appear to be ELF new 32-bit LSB executable, MIPS, MIPS-I version 1 (SYSV)

Comment: Ok.  What's the difference?  Probably just some ELF header field.  Which field is it, and what's the value difference?  That will point you to the right flags.

Comment: I found the answer by myself. I was just looking for proper cros-compiler and finally found it.

Comment: <http://www.uclibc.org/downloads/binaries/> uClibc binary packges are equipped with right cross-compiler. I hope this information will help anyone